# How to resolve the 4429 error in Azure TTS?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use Unity to develop my software and I have access to the Azure SDK, using code that is basically officially provided, it fails every few days and then every time I call it I get this error reported:

Connection was closed by the remote host. Error code: 4429. Error details: The request is throttled because you have exceeded the concurrent request limit allowed for your sub USP state: 3. Received audio size: 0 bytes.

What I know so far.

1. If I delete the resource in Azure, recreate the new TTS resource, and change the secret key to the new resource's secret key, I can temporarily fix the problem
2. The problem is not caused by me calling it too many times in a short period of time, I have tried calling it more times than the limit in a short period of time and this causes another error
3. This problem does not resolve itself over time, I have tried not calling it all day and the next day the problem is still the same

My current suspicions.

1. could it be that I sent some kind of request or something, but didn't destroy it, and that caused the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved, it's the free credit that ran out